# Is it even useful to write my own Vector3D and Matrix 3D classes in XNA?

Tags: 3d, xna

For school I am to write a 3D game ( very trivial pool game ), using 3D algebra in order to simulate the physics. In 2D games, I wrote my own Vector and Matrix classes, which worked fine, since I don't have to convert from 3D to 2D all the time, which is a lot more difficult, as I'm now pretty stumped at some very basic calculations, such as collision detection between a ball and a wall.
But I would really like to learn working with Matrices and vectors, in such a way that I know what I'm doing, and not just let XNA do all the work. So my question is this:
the game has to be ready in 8 weeks time, is it convenient, or even useful to write my own Vector and Matrix classes, or will this take me too long? Thanks in advance!

greetz, Geekpeek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a good understanding of 3D principles, you *must* have a good understanding of how 3D vectors and matrix transforms work - including homogeneous transforms and projections. By all means, use pre-existing code to get this done, but there's no reason you can't work on your own stuff at the same time. Just keep it quarantined from your project.

Answer (score 1):

That is a hard question to answer, but generally never repeat something that someone has done before.  Only write what you find that you need to.  If your school doesn't require it do not do it.  The time you spend writing that will take away from the overall quality of your game.

Time is money.